# How to delete a specific range when specific cell is empty?

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following problem.
In an excel spreadsheet I am populating a calendar schedule.
Based on a drop down list, you can change the months and year, and therefore the dates adjust automatically to the week days.

```
Fixed week days = `E6:R6`   
Calendar dates  = `E7:R7`    
Work Shifts     = `E8:R15`
```

[image]

Now, when the new schedule populates and like in this case, there is no "Sunday" before October 1st, then I need to have all names from range `E8:E15` removed.

[image]

I've tried an IF THEN ELSEIF in the sub, and that works, but only for the first range - `E8:E15`.  If I switch the month to September, and we start with a Saturday, then all cells maintain their values, but `E8:E15`.  It's like I can only do "1" IF loop and then it stops.

[image]

I'm looking for code that loops through all weeks to check if the cell shows a date or is empty.  The only possible weeks with no dates would be week 1, and week 5 + 6. As you can see in the last pic, depending on how long the month is, more or less dates show.

[image]

---

UPDATE:
Hi there, it works now and I was able to work it out the following way.

**My original code was:**

```
If Sheets("schedule").Range("E5") = "" Then
Sheets("Schedule").Range("E8:E15").ClearContents
  Elseif Sheets("schedule").Range("G5") = "" Then
  Sheets("Schedule").Range("G8:G15").ClearContents
```

..and so on for all other ranges of my calendar.
End if

**The new code is:**
What I simply tried next was leaving them all separate.

```
If Sheets("schedule").Range("E5") = "" Then
Sheets("Schedule").Range("E8:E15").ClearContents
End if

If Sheets("schedule").Range("G5") = "" Then
Sheets("Schedule").Range("G8:G15").ClearContents
End if
```

.... and so on.

And now it's running just fine.
For some reason it was not able to run through several IF-loops before the end if.
Thanks everyone for all the fast help!
I'll definitely be back when I have another question about Excel and VBA :)

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52377637/edit) to your question, not a screenshot  - this helps us help you.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, then you are over-complicating this task bigtime, and you don't need VBA at all, just a simple `=IF` statement in a worksheet formula, copy-and-pasted to neighbouring cells. How do the names get there in the first place? For example, in your second image, 'Sunday' column, is there a formula in the cell that says "Calvin"?  If so, wrap an `=IF` statement around it to check if the cell belwo "Sunday" is blank. If so, this cell should also be blank.

Comment: Note that it's tough to know what's going on or to discuss it since your images don't show row/column numbers, and there's no telling if/where there are any formulas on your spreadsheet. (And, as mentioned, screen shots okay for a general overview but not for finding problems in code/formulas.) See "[ask]" as well as **how to create a [mcve]**. Also check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) and see the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on topic on this site.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the feedback so far. Not adding the row/column numbers makes absolute sense. That was dumb.

Comment: @BigBen - This is the coding I had so far..  Sub BuildSchedule()

If Sheets("Schedule").Range("E5") = "" Then
Sheets("Schedule").Range("E8:E15").ClearContents
ElseIf Sheets("Schedule").Range("G5") = "" Then
Sheets("Schedule").Range("G8:H15").ClearContents
ElseIf Sheets("Schedule").Range("I5") = "" Then
Sheets("Schedule").Range("I8:J15").ClearContents
ElseIf Sheets("Schedule").Range("K5") = "" Then
Sheets("Schedule").Range("K8:L15").ClearContents
....

Comment: ElseIf Sheets("Schedule").Range("M5") = "" Then
                Sheets("Schedule").Range("M8:N15").ClearContents
                    ElseIf Sheets("Schedule").Range("O5") = "" Then
                    Sheets("Schedule").Range("O8:P15").ClearContents
                        ElseIf Sheets("Schedule").Range("Q5") = "" Then
                        Sheets("Schedule").Range("Q8:R15").ClearContents
End If

End Sub

Comment: @ashleedawg The name get in there by a simple drop-down list. So the cell itself is basically empty and then gets filled as you select a name from the drop down list

Comment: You are stating at the top of your question that the `Calendar dates  = E7:R7`, but you want to use row 5, this does not make sense? What row is the calendar date on. And what column does Sunday start on? Is your calendar a line or do the weeks sit one upon the other?

Comment: Also, don't put code in the comments, edit your question with any new code or information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by assuming that range("E8:E15").clearcontents is not a typo despite being a single column while all others are 2 columns.

Code¹:

```
sub buildSched()

    dim c as long

    with worksheets("schedule")
        for c = 5 to 17 step 2
            if .cells(5, c).value2 = vbnullstring
                .cells(8, c).resize(8, 1 + abs(cbool(c > 5))).clearcontents
            end if
        next c
    end with

end sub
```

If range("E8:E15").clearcontents *was* a typo and you should be clearing two columns every iteration then use,

```
.cells(8, c).resize(8, 2).clearcontents
```

---

¹ <sub>Note code that can be copied and pasted from the page directly into a module code sheet in the VBE. **Not** an image of code that would require retyping to test/debug.</sub>